# SSH Keys for the Common User. cannot establish key chain. RaspBerry pi 2 model B

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, rsa

I try to establish passwords-less communication between mpi of my notes by using some video tutorial. However, at some point what I saw at the screen of the tutorial differ from from what I saw on my screen. As a result I fault to establish needed connection. I guess is that video tutorial missed some steps therefore I didn't get expected result. Let me guide you through the steps. 
White screen will be screen of the tutor and black will be mine.

So I successfully establish connection between mpiu of notes I can enter exit ssh ls -la and do other things between my notes and mpiu of the notes. However, each time when I enter to the mpiu the system ask me the passwd so this step I wanna get rid of. For that matter:

1. I generate RSA key for the rpi0 ( my first note ) and `ssh-copy` it to the rpi1 ( my second note )
2. I checked that RSA key located on the both notes for `mpiu@rpi1` it will be authorized_key file (as far as i'm understand ) 
   for the mpiu@rpi0 it will be files id_rsa and id_rsa_pub
3. Now I need to make changes in rpi0 .bashrc file to establish key chain ( here problems begun )

3.1. So I went to home directory,  I used vim in order to to edit file

3.2. Here I notice some difference in the file of tutor and mine - the tutor said that in the very end I should add some logic. However, in my file there are two `fi` , the tutor .bashrc file has only one fi at the end.

3.3. So I added logic after the second `fi` ( I saw that `fi` it states from finish => `}` - so probably it is true end )

3.4. that tutor enter command to apply the changes to the system

3.5. the tutor got this everything ok 
but I got this 
( take a look at the White-tutor---done-----black---mine-.pdf )

4. My first thought was I just need to download from the given website ( `funtoo.org` ) needed program and put it in the needed directory. However, the system deny my copy-past procedure by saying that I I have not rights. 
   So what should I do ?  May be I should install the contain of the zip file to my note ( `rpi0` ) by using some Linux command through the terminal  ?

[RSA-Check-and-bashrc-files-.pdf][1]
[White-tutor---done-----black---mine-.pdf][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everybody thx for attention. I solved the problem by installing needed programs through the terminal as I thought.